# extend controller in zend Controller

Tags: zend-framework

hi 
how to extend a controller class from another controller class inside a module?
for eg: i have a module default and a controller defaultController
i want to extend the default controller in userController which is in user module?
i am getting a fatal error when trying to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For re-useable controller functionality you should either use a common parent class for *both* controllers, instead extending one controller by another, or you should use action-helpers.

Comment: the common features are in default controller and it is in  module default. i want to get these default controller in all other module controllers. i tried with action helper but   i cannot able to get Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract object in the action helper.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583636/modular-web-site-with-zend-framework-stack-of-actions

Comment: i am trying to implement the solution described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583636/modular-web-site-with-zend-framework-stack-of-actions.. but i have a modular structure... so as mention  in the given link i have a base controller in the  default module which cannot be able to extend to other controller. is there a better solution for this situation?

Comment: @guny I just can repeat myself: The common features should not be in a requestable controller. An by the way its just way much easier to implement one generic parent controller-class inside your personal library ;)

Comment: actually i am newbie in zend framework and i have learnt about action helper, plugin in library but how cum a parent controller class inside ?

Comment: can u please suggest some helpful documents to implement this

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelper.writingyourown

Comment: hi  i created a base controller in my library  and extended it  to all other controllers in the module and it work fine. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try too look at this example

My directory struckture
+application
 
+-configs
+-modules
+--front
+---controllers
+---views
+----helpers
+----scripts
+-----index
+--user
+---controllers
+---views
+----helpers
+----scripts
+-----index
+library
+public

**application/configs/application.ini**

```
[production]
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "Zend_"
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "My_"

phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"

bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"

resources.modules[] = ''
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.moduleControllerDirectoryName = "controllers"
resources.frontController.defaultModule = "front"
resources.frontController.throwErrors = false

resources.router.routes.default.route = ":module/:controller/:action/*"
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.module = front
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.controller = index
resources.router.routes.default.defaults.action = index

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

**application/bootstrap.php**

```
<?php

class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{


}
```

**application/modules/front/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * IndexController
 * 
 * @author
 * @version 
 */
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php';
class IndexController extends My_Controller_Action_Abstract
{
    /**
     * The default action - show the home page
     */
    public function indexAction ()
    {
        echo('Front Controller');
    }
}
```

**application/modules/user/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * IndexController
 * 
 * @author
 * @version 
 */
require_once 'Zend/Controller/Action.php';
class User_IndexController extends My_Controller_Action_Abstract
{
    /**
     * The default action - show the home page
     */
    public function indexAction ()
    {
        echo('User Controller');
    }
}
```

Comment: my user class   class User_IndexController extends Default_IndexController
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
//      if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) 
//      {
//       $this->view->name=$_POST['username'];
//      }
    }

class Default_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{}
}